# How to forward windows log using Nxlog to rsyslog server(linux)?

Tags: windows, logging, syslog, nxlog

Im using nxlog version 3.0 on WinServ2012 R2 Standard, i can forward the event logs under Eventviewer --> windows logs --> application, system, security. But Im not able to forward other log that is on different log directory/levels for example(screenshot)

[image]

below is my nxlog configuration file nxlog.conf , im trying to grab the usb drive/pen drives insert/eject logs from `Microsoft-Windows-DriverDriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational` event log. Logs are populated but im not able to receive them at the syslog server.

```
Panic Soft
define ROOT C:\Program Files (x86)\nxlog
define CERTDIR %ROOT%\cert
define CONFDIR %ROOT%\conf
define LOGDIR %ROOT%\data
define LOGFILE '%LOGDIR%/nxlog.log'
Moduledir %ROOT%\modules
CacheDir %ROOT%\data
Pidfile %ROOT%\data\nxlog.pid
SpoolDir %ROOT%\data
LogLevel INFO

<Extension _syslog>
    Module      xm_syslog
</Extension>

<Extension _charconv>
    Module      xm_charconv
    AutodetectCharsets iso8859-2, utf-8, utf-16, utf-32
</Extension>
<Extension _exec>
    Module      xm_exec
</Extension>
<Extension _fileop>
    Module      xm_fileop
    <Schedule>
        Every   1 hour
        Exec    if (file_exists(%LOGFILE%) and (file_size(%LOGFILE%) >= 5M)) file_cycle(%LOGFILE%, 8);
    </Schedule>
</Extension>
<Input eventlog>
    Module       im_msvistalog
    ReadFromLast TRUE
    <QueryXML>
       <QueryList>
         <Query Id='1'>
            <Select Path='Application'>*</Select>
            <Select Path='Security'>*</Select>
            <Select Path='System'>*</Select>
            <Sekect Path='Microsoft-Windows-DriverDriverFrameworks-UserMode/Operational'>*</Select>
         </Query>
       </QueryList>
   </QueryXML>
</Input>

<Input agentlogging>
    Module      im_internal
</Input>

<Output logcontents>
    Module       om_tcp
    Host         10.10.10.100
    Port         514
    Exec         to_syslog_snare();
</Output>

<Output agentlog>
    Module       om_tcp
    Host         10.10.10.100
    Port         514
    Exec         to_syslog_snare();
</Output>
<Route 1>
    Path        eventlog => logcontents
</Route>

<Route 2>
    Path        agentlogging => agentlog
</Route>
```

Comment: Regarding the syslog forwarding see the [Syslog section in the User Guide](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#syslog). See [this question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6ya1s3/usb_logging_with_nxlog/) about monitoring USB events with NXLog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send syslog from NXLog to a syslog server you'd need to use the xm_syslog extension module and invoke one of the formatters (`to_syslog_bsd()`, `to_syslog_ietf()`, `to_syslog_snare()`) depending on the desired format that your syslog server supports.
For more details see the [Syslog section in the User Guide](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#syslog).

While some USB events stored in the Windows Eventlog, there are other data sources for USB events:

- Windows Event Tracing (ETW). NXLog EE has a module called [im_etw](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#im_etw) that can collect ETW logs directly. See [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1096961) for the list of related ETW providers.
- Windows registry.  USB devices are enumerated under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB` and by monitoring this registry hive it is possible to detect changes to the USB configuration. The [im_regmon](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide#im_regmon) input module supports registry monitoring in the NXLog EE.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working, with trial/error:-

1. In the nxlog.conf file , change the param inside  `<Input eventlog>`
   `ReadFromLast TRUE` to `ReadFromLast FALSE` and comment the lines(put hash# infront)

   #
   *#*
   #
2. Restart nxlog service from task manager
3. Uncomment the previously commented lines again

4. restart the nxlog service
5. Insert the USB pendrive into windows2012 machine and check logs

and I got the logs starting to showup,Im still not sure what triggred this thing..
since i want to read logs from last ,I changed the `ReadFromLast FALSE` to `ReadFromLast TRUE` and logs still are showing up

Comment: Note that `RedFromLast FALSE` will instruct it to read the whole eventlog on the first start which might not be what most people want if there is a lot of historic data.